# Get like count of a facebook post then save it to another places

Tags: c#, facebook

I'm developing a WP 8 app by using Facebook C# SDK, and for now, I want to get "like count" of a post.

Here is my code, everything works well but the return value, it's always "null" because like_count.like_count is never assigned to. I don't know how to assign it in my code.

The line

```
like_count.like_count = like_info["total_count"].ToString();
```

has value "200" but the line

```
return like_count.like_count;
```

returns null!

```
private string GetLikes(string id)
    {
        like_comment like_count = new like_comment();
        FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);
        fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()
                    =>
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message)
                    );
                return;
            }

            var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();
            var like_info = (JsonObject)result["summary"];
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()
                =>
                {
                    like_count.like_count = like_info["total_count"].ToString();
                }
                );
        };
        fb.GetTaskAsync("/"+id+"/likes?summary=1");
        return like_count.like_count;
    }
```

Hope someone can help me :(

Comment: How is you like_comment() object structured?

Comment: public string like_count;
public string comment_count;

Comment: Well, that doesn't make much sense from my point of view. Why don't you just create a temporary string variable and populate this  with like_info["total_count"].ToString() and return it?

Comment: I tried, but it is still not work.
I think the problem is I can't assign to the variable, or the variable can't receive data before "return"

Answer (score 0):

The following doesn't work?

```
private string GetLikes(string id)
{
    FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);
    fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()
                =>
                MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message)
                );
            return;
        }

        var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();
        var like_info = (JsonObject)result["summary"];
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()
            =>
            {
                return like_info["total_count"].ToString();
            }
            );
    };
    fb.GetTaskAsync("/"+id+"/likes?summary=1");
}
```

Comment: not work, you have to return outside fb.getcomplete



Error 1 Since 'System.EventHandler<Facebook.FacebookApiEventArgs>' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression D:\10IFsWPApps\10IFS\10IFS\Pages\LandingPage.xaml.cs 143 18 10IFS

Comment: Well, I can't try it here... As you wrote in your second last comment, return is called before the GetTaskAsync() is completed

Comment: What I have to do for now is how to await GetTackAsync and await eventhandler fb.Getcompleted

Comment: See the sample at https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-windows-phone-sample/blob/master/src/facebook-windows-phone-sample/Pages/FacebookInfoPage.xaml.cs

Comment: It's no use, all of method in that sample is "void", not string.

Comment: Well, apparanty they're displaying it directly in the view. See GraphApiSample(). I'm out.

Comment: thank you, I can display it directly in the view, but for storage, it's still impossible :(